# Speed up the searching of GridView images names -Android

Tags: android, gridview

I wanna to search in Gridview images based on names, however, the search process is very slow! How can I speed up it in gridview?

> The code that I used for search action Is:

**Search EditText action listener:**

```
editSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start,
                int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            textlength = editSearch.getText().length();
            array_sortnames.clear();
            array_sortcodes.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < itemsNames.size(); i++) {
                if (textlength <= itemsNames.get(i).length()) {
                    if (ProjectEngine
                            .getItemName(context, itemsNames.get(i))
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .contains(
                                    editSearch.getText().toString()
                                            .toLowerCase().trim())) {
                        array_sortnames.add(itemsNames.get(i));
                        array_sortcodes.add(imagePaths.get(i));

                    }
                }
            }
            AppendList(array_sortnames, array_sortcodes);
        }
    });
}
```

**AppendList To update GrtidView Adapter:**

```
public void AppendList(ArrayList<String> str, ArrayList<String> str2) {
        customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(GridViewActivity.this,
                layout, str2, columnWidth, str);
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
}
```

any help will be appriciated,

Answer (score 1):

This is not that easy to say, you could reduce the functions calls by extracting

> editSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim()

this to variable

but also it is important what

> ProjectEngine.getItemName(context,itemsNames.get(i)).toLowerCase().contains(editSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim()))

actually does, maybe it is doing some complex stuff... or generally slow stuff, also you should block at least for a few milliseconds or while one search is running that another search can be started... because people will type faster then your script can keep up anyway..

```
editSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private boolean isSearching=false;

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start,
                int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if(this.isSearching==true) {
               return;
            }
            String editText = editSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            this.isSearching=true;
            textlength = editSearch.getText().length();
            array_sortnames.clear();
            array_sortcodes.clear();
            try {
              for (int i = 0; i < itemsNames.size(); i++) {
                if (textlength <= itemsNames.get(i).length()) {
                    if (ProjectEngine
                            .getItemName(context, itemsNames.get(i))
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .contains(
                                    editText)) {
                        array_sortnames.add(itemsNames.get(i));
                        array_sortcodes.add(imagePaths.get(i));

                    }
                }
              }
            } catch(Exception e) {}
            this.isSearching=false;
            AppendList(array_sortnames, array_sortcodes);
        }
    });
}
```

with this method it generates way less overhead, there are some more things that can be considered because when you are typing there is no other search then the running one, also it could be usefull to say "you need at least 3 characters before the search actually makes sense" because when someone hits an "e" you probably get every entry from of what you saved... that could be... very much :D

Comment: I do not understand this please " you should block at least for a few milliseconds or while one ... " ?!

Comment: thanks for your answer also for your way (with faces and fun :)) ... !

Comment: For further optimizing I need simply to know more about whats happening outside of this function :) but I hope it helps and prevents your search from breaking

Comment: Upvote your answer ,, yes it's really helped me .. although now I am in list of errors and bugs from other causes :) ... thanks again @Soulan for your way in answering ...

Comment: No problem at all, I just made up one more thing that actually reduces the needed function calls, it could make a small difference... but that also depends on the amount of data that you want to search, so then good luck again :)